# How can I make a bot ignore case while only responding to a sentence if it contains a certain word or phrase?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been working on a bot for a friend server and I was wondering if there was a way to make a bot respond if a sentence contains a certain word or phrase. I can get to the point where I can have it respond to something in a sentence or ignore case, I just can't get it to do both at the same time. Here is an example of the simple code I've been using:

```
 if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'ping')
        message.channel.send('pong')
```

Is there a way to add in .includes so it will respond no matter what?

Comment: `'bing bang ping'.toLowerCase().includes('ping')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.content` contains a string.
Strings have a method called `toLowerCase` and a method called `includes`

`toLowerCase` also returns a string, so you can just add `.includes("ping")` after the last ().

`if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('ping') { //do stuff }`